# Setting RecordSet to stored procedure results. Attempting to sort/filter results in Data Provider could not be Initialized

Tags: vba, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2013

My team and I support a large network of MS access applications. Recently we upgraded our Microsoft Office from 2010 to 2013. The only thing that broke in this upgrade was our ability to sort/filter datasheets that are populated from an ADO RecordSet. Attempting to filter results in an error

> Data Provider could not be initialized

From my research I understand that Microsoft considers ADO deprecated and has stopped supporting ADO as a means of populating RecordSets.

I'm however in a specific bind and have been trying every "fix" I could find in order to get this datasheet filterable. I am open to all suggestions.

The closest I have gotten is by populating the datasheet via a stored procedure:

```js
 Dim cn As New ADODB.connection
   
   Dim cm As New ADODB.Command
   
  
   Set cn = New ADODB.connection
      With cn
         .Provider = "Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0"
         .Properties("Data Provider") = "SQLNCLI10"
         .Properties("Data Source") = "ascsql2012sbox"
         .Properties("Integrated Security") = "SSPI"
         .Properties("Initial Catalog") = "assetQuality_dev"
      End With
   
   cn.Open
  
   Dim rs As ADODB.recordset
   Set rs = New ADODB.recordset
   With cm
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandText = "dbo.accountIDproc"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .parameters.Refresh
        End With
        With rs
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        End With
        
    Set rs = cm.Execute
    
    cm.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    
    Set Me.recordset = rs
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
```

But the same error

> Data provider could not be initialized

is still showing up whenever I try to sort a column from A-Z or Z-A. For some columns that contain an integer value. It asks me for a value to sort by then tells me "that's not a valid value" when it's absolutely a valid value.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why not use a temp table or linked table and then have datasheet bound to it?

Comment: @Parfait Thank you! Yes I did exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question with a pretty solid solution as suggested by @parfiat

I created a temp table then inserted values from a recordset. I then set the temp table to the DAO.recordset which my datasheet pulls from. Here's my coded solution:

```js
  
    Set rs = New ADODB.recordset
    Set cn2 = New ADODB.connection
    With cn2
       .Provider = "Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0"
       .Properties("Data Provider") = "SQLNCLI10"
       .Properties("Data Source") = "ascsql2012sbox"
       .Properties("Integrated Security") = "SSPI"
       .Properties("Initial Catalog") = "assetQuality_dev"
    End With
    cn2.Open
    cn2.CommandTimeout = 0
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    rs.Source = "SELECT " & sqlSelect & " FROM " & sqlFrom & IIf(sqlWhere <> "", " WHERE " & sqlWhere, "") & IIf(sqlOrder <> "", " ORDER BY " & sqlOrder, "")
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn2
    rs.Open
      
    If AccessTableExists("ThisTable") = True Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable = acDefault, "ThisTable"
    End If
    
    ' Create temp table
    Dim dbs As Database
  
    ' on your computer
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
 
    ' Create a table with two text fields.
    dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE ThisTable " _
    & "(accountID int, customerName CHAR, phoneHome VARCHAR(25), taxID VARCHAR(9), address VARCHAR(200), addressState VARCHAR(2), addressCity VARCHAR(2), bank VARCHAR(35), dateReview VARCHAR(200), orderDateReview VARCHAR(100), dateDue VARCHAR(100), balCustomer VARCHAR(200), activityCode VARCHAR(100), dateActivity VARCHAR(100), accountNumber VARCHAR(25));"
   
    dbs.Close
     
    Dim dbsTemp As DAO.Database
    Dim rstemp As DAO.recordset
 
    Set dbsTemp = CurrentDb
    Set rstemp = dbsTemp.OpenRecordset("ThisTable", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
    rstemp.AddNew
    rstemp!accountID.value = rs!accountID.value
    rstemp!customerName.value = rs!customerName.value
    rstemp!balCustomer.value = rs!balCustomer.value
    rstemp!accountNumber.value = rs!accountNumber.value
    rstemp!dateDue.value = rs!dateDue.value
    rstemp!taxID.value = rs!taxID.value
    rstemp!phoneHome.value = rs!phoneHome.value
    rstemp!dateReview.value = rs!dateReview.value
    rstemp!activityCode.value = rs!activityCode.value
    rstemp!dateActivity.value = rs!dateActivity.value
    rstemp.update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
    Set Me.recordset = rstemp
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn2.Close
    Set cn2 = Nothing
```